# PHP output buffer stacking

Tags: php, buffer

The following is not achieving what I desire

```
<?
echo ob_start() . "<br>";
echo "1x<br>";
echo ob_start() . "<br>";
echo "2x<br>";
echo ob_flush() . "<br>";
echo "3x<br>";
echo ob_flush() . "<br>";
?>
```

The output is the following

```
1
1x
1
2x
1
3x
1
```

I am wanting something along the lines of

```
1x
3x
2x
```

I assume the problem is its putting the output from the second ob_start() in the first output buffer. But how do I get my desired output?

Basically what I am trying to achieve is providing the  tag which needs to be in the head of a HTML document at a latter point in the output. Ie, half way through the script after it has already printed the docs head infomation it needs to then provide the .

Comment: I believe you should tell us a little more about the context of the issue, because there are multiple ways to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the PHP manual for [ob_start](https://www.php.net/ob_start). You don't want to

```
echo ob_start();
```

because that function returns true or false, so it will output a 1 or 0
instead

```
ob_start();
echo "1x" . "<br />";
echo "2x" . "<br />";
echo "3x" . "<br />";
ob_flush();
```

Overall your objective isn't very clear. ob_start() is used for cleaning up a bunch of output before it is sent. It shouldn't be used as a stack.

Try [SplStack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splstack.php) if you want to use a stack in PHP.

Comment: I know those function calls return 0 or 1. I was just printing them to prove they were being called correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just write

```
echo "1x"."<br>";
echo "3x"."<br>";
echo "2x"."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
<?php
echo ob_start();
echo "1x<br>";
$keep_me_1 = ob_get_contents(); /* optional and for later use */
echo ob_flush();

echo ob_start();
echo "3x<br>";
$keep_me_2 = ob_get_contents(); /* optional and for later use  */
echo ob_flush();

echo ob_start();
echo "3x<br>";
$keep_me_3 = ob_get_contents(); /* optional and for later use  */
echo ob_flush();

?>
```

If you want to use more of the "stack" functionality you should take a look at [`ob_end_flush`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php).

Comment: This is how I actually did it. Very close to what you described however you need to call ob_clean() instead of ob_flush() 

ob_start();
echo "1<br>";
$g_ob[] = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

ob_start();
echo "2<br>";
$g_ob[] = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

ob_start();
echo "3<br>";
$g_ob[] = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

echo $g_ob[0];
echo $g_ob[2];
echo $g_ob[1];

Answer (score 0):

You can use ob_get_contents() to save the contents of the inner buffer to a string, then call ob_end_clean() to throw the contents away. Later, use a callback function in the outer buffer to write out the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `ob_*` functions should not be `echo`'ed.

```
<?
ob_start() . "<br>";
echo "1x<br>";
ob_start() . "<br>";
echo "2x<br>";
ob_flush() . "<br>";
echo "3x<br>";
ob_flush() . "<br>";
?>
```

[ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) function returns a boolean. So basically, your code is simply echoing a `true` value, which translates as `1` when converted to a string.